# how to recognize a signal trend using pine

Tags: pine-script

I'm using this code to find SMI at the last candle close time.

```
a = input(10, "Percent K Length")
b = input(3, "Percent D Length")
ob = input(40, "Overbought")
os = input(-40, "Oversold")
// Range Calculation
ll = lowest (low, a)
hh = highest (high, a)
diff = hh - ll
rdiff = close - (hh+ll)/2

avgrel = ema(ema(rdiff,b),b)
avgdiff = ema(ema(diff,b),b)

// SMI calculations
SMI = avgdiff != 0 ? (avgrel/(avgdiff/2)*100) : 0

SMIsignal = ema(SMI,b)
emasignal = ema(SMI, 10)
```

The code provides me the current SMIsignal and emasignal at closure time and it works fine.

Is it possible to have the current SMIsignal only if it is lowering in the last 3 (e.g.) candles
and a null (zero) SMIsignal value if the SMIsignal is not lowering in the last 3 (e.g.) candles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SMItmp = float(na)
SMItmp := ema(SMI,b)
sig = SMItmp[3]<SMItmp[2] and SMItmp[2]<SMItmp[1] and SMItmp[1]<SMItmp[0]
SMIsignal = sig ? SMItmp : na
```